# What exactly mean "No Outbound Networking" in free tier on Google Firebase functions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebase

In Google Firebase pricing (https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) table states:

> The Spark plan only allows outbound network requests to Google-owned
>   services.

Does it mean that JS function in web browser (client) page can't call Firebase function and retrieve data in FREE TIER?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your client was using some Google service as a proxy, or you change you design for the web server to pull the data from a google hosted site, it will not work from a client on your network.

I have played a bit with their Nest thermostat dev tools, which use firebase. They would be allowed to use the free tier as a backend database, as their dev tools are run in their cloud.

Answer (score 3):

The pricing tag has a question mark, it says that `The Spark plan allows outbound network requests only to Google-owned services. Inbound invocation requests are allowed within the quota. On the Blaze plan, Cloud Functions provides a perpetual free tier. The first 2,000,000 invocations, 400,000 GB-sec, 200,000 CPU-sec, and 5 GB of Internet egress traffic is provided for free each month.`

If someone sends requests to your functions, these requests are inbounded requests. And It does have a 5 GB egress qouta per month. However, if you have to use other services, like fetch other url outside google, is prohibited in Free tier.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer imo...  :)